# Corda Enterprise performance test suite

Tags: corda

I downloaded the trial version of Corda Enterprise 4.0 for evaluation . Wanted to try out the jmeter corda test suite.
The document says available to registered user of Corda Enterprise in the same location as the Corda Enterprise artifacts. is it available in the trial version ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the current Corda Enterprise 4.0 Evaluation pack - it is missing the test suite zip file that contains the example files referenced in the documentation.

**Update:** The missing zip file has been added under `tools/jmeter-testuite/jmeter-corda-4.0-testsuite.zip`. Re-downloading the evaluation pack should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After you unzip the Enterprise evaluation .zip file, the jmeter suite should be available under tools > developer-pack > repository > com > r3 > corda > jmeter-corda (you'll need to untar developer-pack.tar.gz).

Comment: I could find the jmeter-corda folder , but the contents of this have only 3 files , jmeter-corda-4.0.jar , jmeter-corda-4.0.pom and jmeter-corda-4.0-javadoc.jar.
As per the documentation there should be jmeter-corda-<version>-testsuite.zip

Comment: @PoojaKamat I think those docs are a bit outdated and the file name has changed. I also think the only thing you need to actually run the jmeter suite is `jmeter-corda.jar` (`corda-ptflows-<version>.jar` is also available in the developer pack folder).

Comment: Okay, and what about the sample jmeter.properties and sample-server-rmi.config ?

Answer (score 0):

The Corda Enterprise Performance Test suite is updated at Corda Enterprise 4.0 Evaluation pack.